# Android Move the whole screen upwards when softkeypad is opened?

Tags: android

i just want to shift my whole activity screen upwards when the user clicks on the edit text...
i mean the screen will shift upwards and below it we can see the soft keypad...
I have tried using  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" in my Manifest file but it doesn't make any sense.. 
thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml layout. Make the scrollview to be root parent, and it will work!

Try this to detect if keyboard is up, and then scroll down (you need your scroll to be root in xml):

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        //keyboard is visible
        if (heightDiff > 100) {
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i have done it but its not completely scrolling the screen to bottom...plz chk it urself...thanks

Comment: scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN); 
    } 
});

Comment: couldn't get the solution yet....could you give the source of a simple app which resolves my issue ? the thing is iam not able to scroll the view programmatically when the keyboard is visible...method not working ..thanks in advance

Comment: in  scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN) what type is scroll its giving me error ?

Comment: It's your ScrollView. The one you have as root parent in xml layout.